# LiteIDE with gvm. Build, run, and fmt won't work. Environment issues?

Tags: linux, go, liteide

I've set up go (golang) on my Linux Mint (Ubuntu) box using gvm (Go Version Manager).

I've started a project, but I can't get it to build from within LiteIDE.

```
go build -i [/home/username/go/src/projectname]
Error: process failed to start.
```

If I open a terminal and cd to the project's location and do a `go build` it works just fine.  My go env seems to work just fine outside of liteide.

Answer (score 2):

The GOROOT is not set correctly in LiteIDE.

In a terminal enter `which go` to know where gvm installed go.  Example:

```
/home/username/.gvm/gos/go1.6/bin/go
```

In LiteIDE, click on the grey box "edit current environment" right of the environment drop down menu.

[image: LiteIDE drop down menu]

Uncomment the GOROOT line in the system.env file and enter the correct path that you got from `which go`.  You omit "/bin/go".

```
GOROOT=/home/username/.gvm/gos/go1.6
```

Save the file.  If saving is greyed out, you might need to change the permission of LiteIDE's `liteenv` directory.  I installed mine to `/opt/liteide/share/liteide/liteenv`.

When the settings are configured correctly, this is what you should see in LiteIDE's Build Output window:

`/home/username/.gvm/gos/go1.6/bin/go build -i [/home/username/go/src/project]
Success: process exited with code 0.
/home/username/go/src/bad/bad  [/home/username/go/src/project]
Hello World!
Success: process exited with code 0.`

Instead of using the system environment config (the default in the drop down menu) I'm personally using the linux64-local.env file. My LiteIDE config file looks like this:

```
# native compiler linux amd64

GOROOT=/home/username/.gvm/gos/go1.6
#GOBIN=
GOARCH=amd64
GOOS=linux
CGO_ENABLED=1

PATH=$GOROOT/bin:$PATH

LITEIDE_GDB=gdb
LITEIDE_MAKE=make
LITEIDE_TERM=/usr/bin/gnome-terminal
LITEIDE_TERMARGS=
LITEIDE_EXEC=/usr/bin/xterm
LITEIDE_EXECOPT=-e

LITEIDE_SHELL=gnome-terminal;lxterminal;kconsole;xfce4-terminal;xterm
```